# Cluster safe database populating on startup

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, locking

I need to update possibly changed Java enum values to PostgreSQL 9.3 database on application start up. How to make this cluster safe so that only one instance does the update? Is it enough to use `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` when populating the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite right:

```
LOCK TABLE thetable IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

is entirely appropriate. Just make sure there's no race condition where some other session can access the table before your update session gets the lock.